# Are object of my classes being created everytime there is a request or does it only create one instance of a class per instance server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, jax-rs

The reason i am asking is because i am wondering if I should declare an object as a field and initialise it in the constructor even though it is only used by one method or I should only initialise it inside the method when the method is called

**this**

```
 @Path("/user/")
    public class MyUserResource(){
    UserManager userManager;
    PathManager pathManager;

    MyUserResource(){
        userManager = new userManager();//used by many methods in this class
        pathManager = new PathManager(); // used by only one method in this class
    }
    @GET
    @Path("/getPath")
    public getPath(long id){ // That one method using pathManager
        pathManager.doWork(id)
   }
}
```

**VS this**

```
public class MyUserResource(){
    UserManager userManager;

    MyUserResource(){
        userManager = new userManager();//used by many methods in this class
        PathManager pathManager = new PathManager(); // used by only one method in this class

    @GET
    @Path("/getPath")
    public getPath(long id){ // That one method using pathManager
        PathManager pathManager = new PathManager(); 
        pathManager.doWork(id)
   }
}
```

The objects must be created and that requires work by the JVM. In the second example the object is only created when that method is needed but the down side is it could be created 100s of times a minute because it is being called a lot. it could also not be needed at all but the class instantiates it 100s of times because other methods in the class are being called like in the first example. But if GAE only creates on instance then instaniating PathManager in the constructor would be a much better option but i can't find any documentation confirming this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instances of resource classes are created "per-request" by default. You can mark them as singletons however and then one instance would be used for all requests. To do this you can use the following annotations:

- `@com.sun.jersey.spi.resource.Singleton` for Jersey 1.x (JAX-RS 1.1)
- `@javax.inject.Singleton` for Jersey 2.x (JAX-RS 2.0)

Comment: Are there any disadvantages to doing this?

Comment: You need to keep in mind that it's Singleton and that you introduced "kind" of a state to a REST resource. Also this class will consume your memory even if the resource is not used (after the first call).